# MySQL Query where column is specific value or any value

Tags: mysql, laravel

Not specifically a Laravel question, but I am using Laravel Query Builder.  I have a MySQL database column that contains any one of a long list of statuses.  When filtering the list I simply pass the status or statuses as an array to the query...

```
$statusArray = ['active','inProgress'];

DB::table('mytable')->whereIn('status', $statusArray)->get();
```

However when not filtering I want all statuses returned so I would wish for something like...

```
 $statusArray = [*];
```

Is there a simple way to handle this or do I need to dynamically build the `whereIn` clause for the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to see perticular status add them in $statusArray

```
$statusArray = ['active','inProgress'];
```

And when you want to get all statuses declare `$statusArray` as empty array

```
$statusArray = array();
```

Then add condition in eloquent like below

```
DB::table('mytable')->when(!empty($statusArray), function($q, $statusArray) {
   return $q->whereIn('status', $statusArray);
})->get();
```

Comment: Ok cool. I had seen this before but I forgot about the feature.  To work properly I needed to pass the `$statusArray` into the closure.  Using either `function($q,$statusArray)`  or with  'use' `function($q) use ($statusArray)`   Update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

Yo can use the 'when' conditional clause. This will help you add additional conditions to your query when a condition is satisfied and skip the conditions when it is not. (in your case, when the filter is to be applied

See here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses